# How does this site (https://www.oemfordpart.com/) know selenium and display ads?

Tags: selenium

How does this site (https://www.oemfordpart.com/) know selenium and display ads?

The `disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled` method doesn't work.

Comment: I also tried replacing cdc_ with another word using gvim.exe, but it doesn't work.
And since I am using vba, I have not tried the following because I do not know the commands.
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)

Comment: It's impossible to know without attempting to reverse engineer the site.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not self-contained.   Once the linked site changes, this question will be useless to anybody else that has a similar problem.